# PanoramaMissionOperator compatibility with DJI Mavic Pro and Phantom 4 Pro

Tags: dji-sdk

Has anyone used PanoramaMissionOperator on the mobile SDK for android or iOS? I can't see any example code online. Also it seems to be unclear which products support the use of PanoramaMissionOperator from the documentation. When I attempt to get the state of the PanoramaMissionOperator with a Mavic Pro and Phantom 4 Pro, I get a PanoramaMissionState of DISCONNECTED.

I know the DJI documentation describes how to achieve the same with a Waypoint Mission but some drones miss photos during waypoint missions.

```
PanoramaMissionOperator operator = MissionControl.getInstance().getPanoramaMissionOperator();
PanoramaMissionState missionState = operator.getCurrentState();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PanoramaMissions are only supported for OSMO devices, source:
https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/component-guide-missions.html -> scroll to the bottom.

Unfortunately the SDK documentation doesn't mention this and the only hint I got there is the description of the DISCONNECTED state: "The connection between the mobile device and Osmo is broken."
https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIPanoramaMissionState.html#djipanoramamissionstate_disconnected_inline

Comment: Thanks for that! Have you managed to capture a panorama in another way via the dji-sdk?

Comment: The dji-sdk has no way to do that unfortunately. You could make a timeline mission:

- ascend to a certain height
- move yaw by 45°
- take photo
- repeat until you have 8 photos
- Use the MediaManager accessible from Camera to retrieve the photos to your smartphone. MediaFile.Callback tells you when a new MediaFile is retrievable.
- Use something like OpenCV to stich the photots together to create the panorama